# A method of checking my cpu bit

Tags: operating-system, cpu, bit

My OS is **windows 10 x86_64**.

I had checked supporting arm64 the cpu. So I had knew 64bit cpu.

But sometimes, I got error message about OS bit.

So I do cpu bit test on c language.

```
printf("%d", sizeof(int*));
```

I had expected result is 8. But **Result was 4.**

#### 1. What is my cpu bit?

#### 2. if my cpu is 32bit, Can use memory over 4GB? My cpu supports arm64.

Please I'm very confused.

Comment: A 64-bit OS on an x86-64/amd64 CPU usually supports natively the execution of x86 32-bit software, in which that sizeof would hold true. You have a 64-bit processor, but that program was compiled for 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU almost certainly can't be both [arm64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#64-bit) and run [x86_64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) Windows, because the Intel and ARM instruction sets are not the same. Perhaps you meant [AMD64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)? If you search the web for you CPU model, you probably will be able to find out how many bit it is.

Further, keep in mind that the C standard only requires that `int`s be at least 16 bits, not the same size as the machine's native size. I suspect that the compiler you were testing with might not have been aware of the 64-bit capabilities of your CPU, and compiled your code as though your CPU was a 32-bit CPU.

As far as memory support, as far as I know, the [motherboard and CPU model](https://superuser.com/questions/308310/what-limits-a-motherboard-from-supporting-more-memory) will affect the actual amount of memory your system will support.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you CPU supports **amd64**.

The size of the C standard types depends on the [data model](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html).
The size of a pointer depends on the execution mode (long-mode vs compatibility-mode) and **can** be 32-bit even on 64-bit OSes.

If your CPU is 32-bits you could [use more than 4GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) of memory, but since the premises is almost surely false, the easiest solution is simply to recompile for a 64-bits environment.